# Ejecutar solo una instancia de WinForms

Tags: c#

Al instalar mi aplicación de Windows Form creo un ejecutable en el escritorio. Lo que quiero controlar es que si ya hay una instancia abierta no me abra otra, si no que me vuelva a mostrar la que esta abierta anteriormente. Mas bien el primer proceso esta en segundo plano, poder simular lo que hace el NotifyIcon para mostrar el formulario en segundo plano

```
string applicationName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, applicationName, out createdNew))
{
    if (createdNew)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    else
    {
        //Volver a abrir la instancia que ya esta abierta
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu código? ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: @JDev ese es el código

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias opciones. La mas sencilla probablemente es utilizar [`GetProcessesByName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8) para buscar si ya se está ejecutando un proceso con el mismo nombre de nuestra aplicación. Si no lo encontramos, lanzamos la aplicación. Si lo encontramos, mandamos el proceso a primer plano.

Sería algo similar a lo siguiente. Este código lo añadimos en el `Main()` de `Program.cs`:

```
Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
bool procesoAbierto = false;

if (procesos.Length > 1)
{
    foreach (Process proceso in procesos)
    {
        IntPtr frameworkHandle = proceso.MainWindowHandle;
        if (frameworkHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            procesoAbierto = true;
            WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
            wp.showCmd = 3; //lo marcamos como Maximizado

            SetForegroundWindow(frameworkHandle); //A primer plano
            SetWindowPlacement(frameworkHandle, ref wp); //Maximizamos
        }
    }
}

if (procesoAbierto == false)
{
    Application.Run(new tuFormularioPrincipal());
}
```

Este código hace uso de un par de funciones del API. Debemos declararlas de la siguiente manera:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

public struct POINTAPI
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
    public POINTAPI ptMinPosition;
    public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
    public RECT rcNormalPosition;
}
```

Existen otras opciones, como usar [Mutex](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8), pero en mi experiencia el sistema que he propuesto funciona perfectamente para conseguir el objetivo.

---

Por lo que veo, en tu caso el proceso queda en segundo plano y no tiene un formulario, por lo que mi código no funcionaría.Si lo único que quieres es que no se lance otra instancia si ya hay otra corriendo, el código se simplificaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
if (procesos.Length > 1)
{
     //ya se está ejecutando, no hacemos nada
}
else
{
     Application.Run(new tuFormularioPrincipal());
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

A continuación añado una solución para mostrar una ventana oculta de un proceso que ya se está ejecutando:

*Imports:*

```
[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string strClassName, string strWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int ProcessId);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

*Main()*

```
tatic void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    if (procesos.Length > 1)
    {
        MostrarVentanaProcess(procesos, "Form1"); <- Text de la ventana a abrir
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

}
```

*Método MostrarVentanaProcess:*

```
static void MostrarVentanaProcess(Process[] procesos, string tituloVentana) //Unhide Process
{
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    int prcsId = 0;

    do
    {
        handle = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, handle, null, "Form123456");

        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out prcsId);
        foreach (var proceso in procesos)
        {
            if (prcsId == proceso.Id)
            {
                ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                return;
            }
        }
    } while (handle != IntPtr.Zero);

}
```

Comment: Vale gracias, osea no hay forma de mostrar un proceso que queda en segundo plano no? Es que cuando esta en segundo plano creo un notifyicon y queria hacer lo mismo que hace el notify pero con el executable

Comment: @Harman Eso deberías haberlo puesto en la pregunta, ya que es diferente :) O sea, tienes un NotifyIcon y desde ahí puedes volver a abrir el formulario de tu aplicación, y lo que quieres  es que si se vuelve a ejecutar pase lo mismo, es asi? Si lo es, edita la pregunta para aclarar ese tema por favor

Comment: @Harman echa un vistazo a mi _Edit 2_. Creo que debería funcionarte en su caso.

Comment: Si he posteado la solucion abajo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Os pongo la solución si quereis hacer una unica instancia y que si esta instancia esta oculta la muestre de nuevo, ponemos el siguiente código en Program.cs en Main() . Gracias a Pikoh por la ayuda.

```
 /* Importo los Windows API para buscar la ventana y mostrarla */
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool createdNew = true;
            string applicationName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

            /* Busco si este proceso esta en marcha antes */
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, applicationName, out createdNew))
            {
                /* Si no esta en marcha enciendo un nuevo proceso y si no muestro el que esta antes */
                if (createdNew)
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form1());
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                else
                {
                    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Form Name");
                    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```